# Panic only if the returned error is discarded

Tags: go, error-handling

I believe I saw a function in the Go stdlib at some point which, on error, would allow you to handle said error by returning it. However, if you chose to ignore the error, it would panic instead. So, for example:

```
err := theFunction() // No panic

theFunction()        // Panic

_ := theFunction()   // Panic
```

Remembering the function today, I considered how this could have been achieved, but I couldn't think of anything. Perhaps something to do with `defer`?

Regardless, upon deciding to check the source code of said function for some answers, I came to realise that I did not remember its name, or the package it was in. I therefore came here to hopefully learn:

- Are there any such functions / is this possible, or am I misremembering?
- What are some examples of such functions?
- How can this be achieved?

Comment: This is not possible; a function has no way to know what its caller does with any return value(s).

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of a language construct like [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15), which will panic in the `x := y.(Foo)` form but not in the `x,ok := y.(Foo)` form?

Comment: @Adrian I think that might be it actually. It is a distant memory so it's quite likely I misremembered it as a function. Thanks! I'll delete the question since it's getting downvoted to oblivion :P

Comment: There are linters that check your code for ignored errors. Though maybe not really what you are looking for.

Comment: @TehSphinX no no, that's not it. I think it was indeed type assertions as said by Adrian, but thanks for commenting :)

Comment: Typically the solution is to have two functions, a `Thing() error` and a `MustThing()`, where the `Must` version panics instead of returning an error. You can see this in the stdlib in the template and regexp packages.

Comment: @Adrian I see. That is indeed a good alternative. Actually, could you sum up your comments into an answer so I can accept it? This turned out a lot more informative than I expected so I might leave the question after all :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the solution is to have two functions, a `Thing() error` and a `MustThing()`, where the `Must` version panics instead of returning an error. You can see examples of this in the stdlib in the [`template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Must) and [`regexp`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile) packages.